# SQL - 3 column filter

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with 3 columns,

```
ID  ----   Site  ----   Date  
1A  -----  A ----10/12/16  
1A  -----  B ----11/12/16  
2A  -----  A ----10/12/16  
3A  -----  A ----09/12/16  
3A  -----  B ----09/12/16  
4A  -----  A ----11/12/16  
5A  -----  A ----11/12/16  
5A  -----  B ----11/12/16  
6A  -----  A ----09/12/16  
6A  -----  B ----10/12/16
```

I need all rows which have the Primary Site - A
I also need rows with the same ID and Same Date, the Site can be different.
If rows have the same ID but a different date, then I need them filtered out. 
So the table should look like --

```
ID  ----   Site  ----   Date  
1A  -----  A ----10/12/16   
2A  -----  A ----10/12/16  
3A  -----  A ----09/12/16  
3A  -----  B ----09/12/16  
4A  -----  A ----11/12/16  
5A  -----  A ----11/12/16  
5A  -----  B ----11/12/16   
6A  -----  A ----09/12/16
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM yourTable t1
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT ID, Date
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY ID, Date
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) t2
    ON t1.ID   = t2.ID AND
       t1.Date = t2.Date
WHERE t1.Site = 'A' OR
      t2.ID IS NOT NULL
```

**Explanation:**

The subquery identifies `ID`, `Date` pairs for which more than one record appear having these values (ignoring the site).  The join marks these records, which you want to retain.  In the `WHERE` clause, either duplicate records or records having the `'A'` site are retained in the result set.

Answer (score 1):

```
with tb(ID,Site,[Date]) AS(
  select '1A','A','10/12/16' union all
  select '1A','B','11/12/16' union all
  select '2A','A','10/12/16' union all
  select '3A','A','09/12/16' union all
  select '3A','B','09/12/16' union all
  select '4A','A','11/12/16' union all
  select '5A','A','11/12/16' union all
  select '5A','B','11/12/16' union all
  select '6A','A','09/12/16' union all
  select '6A','B','10/12/16')
  select * from (
    SELECT *, count(0)OVER (PARTITION BY ID, Date) AS SameDateCount
    FROM tb
  ) as t where t.site='A' OR t.SameDateCount>1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from 
     (
     SELECT *, rank() OVER (PARTITION BY ID order by id, Date) AS rnk
     FROM yourtable 
     ) tmp where rnk=1
```

Answer (score 0):

if your sql server is 2012 version (or superior), you can use lag

```
select * from 
   (
   select *, lag([Date]) over(partition by ID order by [Date]) as valbefor
   from yourtable
   ) tmp where isnull(valbefor, [Date])=[Date]
```